# Explanation of Ownership in Properties

Tags: properties, vala

I've the following code

```
int main (string[] args) {
    var clock = new Clock ();
    print ("Time now is %s\n", clock.time);
    return 0;
}

public class Clock : Object {
    public string time {
        owned get {
            return get_the_time ().format_iso8601();
        }
    }

    GLib.DateTime get_the_time () {
        return new GLib.DateTime.now ();
    }
}
```

without the `owned` directive I get the following errror

`Return value transfers ownership but method return type hasn't been declared to transfer ownership`

I've the read the memory management part in Vala tutorial but I couldn't fully grasp it. I found that adding owned solved the problem but I don't know if I'm right or wrong.

I appreciate any explanation on this subject.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.DateTime.format_iso8601.html), GLib.DateTime.format_iso8601() returns:

> a newly allocated string formatted in ISO 8601 format or null in the
> case that there was an error. The string should be freed with g_free

Therefore, you need to transfer the ownership of the returned string to your object. Otherwise, the string would be freed when the function returns since a string is not reference counted, and as stated [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ReferenceHandling):

> Non reference counted objects may have only one strong reference
> (think of it as the "owning" reference). When this reference goes out
> of scope the object is freed. All other references must be unowned
> references. When these references go out of scope the object will not
> be freed.

Therefore, you must transfer the ownership of the string returned by format_iso8601() using `owned`.